# show that inequality $(x-3)^4+(y-3)^4+(z-3)^4\ge 193$

Tags: inequality, uvw

Let $x,y,z\in R$,and such
$$xy+yz+xz=-1$$ show that
$$(x-3)^4+(y-3)^4+(z-3)^4\ge 193$$

it seem use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to solve it?But I try sometime can't get this answer,even now I can't find this equality when $=$?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica is not happy (Unless I'm blind and missed an obvious typo). 
$$
x := -\frac{485}{2048} \\
y := -\frac{5}{2048} \\
z := \frac{4196729}{1003520}
$$
Then $xy + yz + zx = -1$ (See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-(485%2F2048)*-5%2F2048+%2B+-5%2F2048*4196729%2F1003520+%2B+4196729%2F1003520*-(485%2F2048))). However
$$
(x-3)^4 + (y-3)^4 + (z-3)^4 = 192.98312371 < 193
$$
See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-485%2F2048+-3)%5E4+%2B(-5%2F2048+-3)%5E4+%2B+(4196729%2F1003520-3)%5E4).

---

Also it seems that Mathematica *FindInstance* cannot disprove your statement in $\mathbb{Z}$ so it **might be** true in this set.

Comment: As an expert *Mathematica* programmer, I would urge extreme caution interpreting the the fact that it did not find a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative, and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, the expression $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x-3)^4$ is a linear expression of $w^3$,

which says that it gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=x$. Thus, $z=-\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$ and 
$$\min_{xy+xz+yz=-1}\sum_{cyc}(x-3)^4=\min\left(2(x-3)^4+\left(-\frac{1+x^2}{2x}-3\right)^4\right)=191.779...,$$
which occurs for $x_1=-0.12...$, where $x_1$ is a negative root of the following equation.
$$11x^6-90x^5+321x^4-180x^3-107x^2-18x-1=0.$$

Comment: Nice,so this problem is right? if $a,b,c$ be postive real numbers,and $\left(\dfrac{a}{b-c}-3\right)^4+\left(\dfrac{b}{c-a}-3\right)^4+\left(\dfrac{c}{a-b}-3\right)^4\ge 193?$,

Comment: @inequality Your last inequality seems true.

Comment: so How to prove it?